# Allow moderator migration selection to use alternate names/URLs

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration, moderator-tools, hyperlinks

We have sites like Cooking, Stats, and Apple which are **Seasoned Advice**, **Cross Validated**, and **Ask Different** respectively. And if I were to go to https://www.seasonedadvice.com or https://www.crossvalidated.com or https://www.askdifferent.com, it will redirect me to the appropriate site.

Yet, if we run into those odd questions that are asked on entirely the wrong site, we can't use these cool names in our migration utility. If I wanted to migrate a perfectly appropriate question to our Cooking site, I can't call it by its name as shown below:

[image: It is advice from Seasoned Adventurers, after all.]

Consider that it isn't a pure name match in the first place - you can find "Software Quality Assurance and Testing" by typing `sqa`, which is the URL for the site. More egregiously, see the following for Motor Vehicles, which otherwise is accessed by typing "motor".

[image: Notice what word isn't even in that title at all.]

It shouldn't be too much of a stretch to allow us to use the special URLs as well, would it?

Comment: +1000000000 for `How do I tell if a corpse is safe to eat?` as an example question.

Comment: If only the branding was consistent

Comment: Don't forget the [`8bitlavapwnpwniebossstagesixforhelp` shortcut](https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts/blob/master/SEChatModifications.user.js#L1357) for Gaming.

Comment: You can do URLs, but `seasoned` gives you nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At some point in time within some period of time yet unknown, this actually got implemented. Sites with special titles will now be accessible in the migration dialog by typing in these titles, in addition to their other forms of address.

[image: Image of Seasoned Advice showing up in the close dialog]